SSH: including hostname in username
Having a need to include hostname in username, attempted to use %h - but it apparently is not supported. Manpage also does not list any token supported in User.
Specifically, for target hosts in some.domain the username has to become user%host.
Preferably, this would be dynamic, where just ssh host would use the hostname from the command.
If User would support the %h token, the config line might look like:
User user%%%h


Similar: https://superuser.com/q/1858019/432690
